# Storing Quill JS data and rendering on mobile applications

Tags: database, blogs, quill, rich-text-editor, react-quill

We're trying to build a content platform with a rich text editor. We decided to use quill editor for the content addition. While checking for methods to store the editor output in the database, found this [comment](https://github.com/quilljs/quill/issues/2276#issuecomment-416034203).

So anyone who had integrated quill or any other rich text editor in a production application could suggest the best possible way to store the contents and render it on the web as well as mobile platforms along with custom styles. thanks in advance.